# ImportError of tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow successfully on my WIN10 cp, but when I tried to import it, import error occurred as below:

```
    import tensorflow
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 87, in preload_check
        ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudnn_dll_name)
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] 找不到指定的模块。

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
        self_check.preload_check()
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 97, in preload_check
        % (build_info.cudnn_dll_name, build_info.cudnn_version_number))
    ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a separate step from installing CUDA, and this DLL is often found in a different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 7 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn
    >>> import tensorflow
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
    File "C:\Users\25457\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

    for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
    above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have already installed CUDA v9.2 and cuDNN 7, also I can find "pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", and it goes well when I installed the CPU version of Tensorflow, but it just don't work for tensorflow gpu. what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: The installation Document specifies CUDA version 9.0 https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. Are you sure it works for 9.2?

Comment: If you are using the pre-built binaries, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605684/support-for-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-9-2. If you are trying to build from source, could you please clarify that in your question?

Comment: I also tried CUDA v9.0 and cuDNN 7.0.4 as well.... still doesn't work

Comment: Could you specify the error for that case? I have it installed on my machine and may be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I reinstalled CUDA V9.0 and cuDNN with 7.0.4
and then reinstalled tensorflow-gpu with 
    pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
    pip install tensorflow-gpu